# Strong separation theorem in dual space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is reflexive. Let $A\colon X\to 2^{X^*}$ be a multivalued map (pseudomonotone). Suppose that $0\notin A(x_0)$. Since $\{0\}$ is compact in $X^*$ and $A(x_0)$ is nonempty, closed, convex and bounded (it follows from psedmononicity of $A$), we apply strong separation theorem to deduce that there exists $f\in X^{**}$ such that 
$$f(0)=0<\inf\{f(x^*)\,|\, x^*\in A(x_0)\}.$$

Since $X$ is reflexive, there is a canonical embedding $\kappa\colon X\to X^{**}$. How to deduce from this, that there exists $u\in X$ such that 
$$0<\inf\{\langle x^*, x_0-u\rangle\,|\, x^*\in A(x_0)\}\,???$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We indentify $f\in X^{**}$ with $\overline{x}\in X$ via $\kappa$. Let $\overline{x} =x_0-u$. We find $u=x_0-\overline{x}$.